# Moodle Form Validation : Using errors array

Tags: moodle

This is a basic question but again after lot of search I could not get how to do.

I am for the first time trying to place custom validations. I have created errors array in validations method of the form. But I do not know where to capture this array.

In a page, I am creating the form as

```
$cnClHpsFrm = new cl_manage_form( $CFG->wwwroot . '/local/hps/cl_manage_hps.php?id='.$currCourseid,array('housesArr'=>$housesArr,'currCrseStudentsArr'=>$currCrseStudentsArr,'currCourseid'=>$currCourseid) );
```

In this same file, I have the three conditions for form cancel, submit and form display.

Please help and guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the validation function returns an non-empty array, then $cnClpHpsFrm->getData() will return false and the display function will include the error messages against the elements matching the array keys of the returned array. So, just check for cancel (and redirect somewhere suitable), then check for getData (process the data and the redirect somewhere suitable), then display the form and it should all just work.

You shouldn't ever need to include the url param when creating a form instance, as forms should usually submit back to the page they started on (so they can redisplay correctly with any validation errors included). As an aside, please follow the Moodle coding guidelines and only use lowercase variable names.

Comment: i will follow your suggestions, thanks for them and replying :)